# People name embedding from name, commas and spaces to keys

Tags: regex, string, word-embedding

I'm trying to figure out a good algorithm for embedding name as such.
space = 0, word = 1, comma = 2, double quotations = 3

So "Bob Dylan" should embed as "101"
While "Brown, Millie Bobby" should embed as "120101"
and "Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson" should embed as "103101301"

Comment: How would it map words not including spaces, double quotes or commas to 1?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood the question

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: What is a “word” for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a very simple solution:

- Search for all the words using `\w+` and replace them with `1`.
- Then for spaces `\s` and replace it with `0`.
- Comma `,` and replace it with `2`.
- And eventually double quote `"` with `3`.